# How do I get rid of these 5k changes shown on my vscode? Also the repo which had some of these changes does not exist anymore

Tags: git, github, version-control

I want to get ride of these changes permanently !

Tried stash drop, rm -rf, git clean

[screen shot of vscode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sj17H.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Yeah it's possible...

In VSCode you can discard changes, which will reset files to the state they were in at the time of the last commit. You can do that by clicking the three dots at the top next to the check mark and the circular arrow and selecting "Discard all changes". That will reset all files.

#### ...but you may not want to do it.

Judging by the files on the screen, it seems like you have initialized a git repository in your home folder, which is really not a good idea. **You should have one repository per project.** In any case the folder ~/.cache/ is probably not something you want to have in your repository, so you might want to add `~/.cache/` and all files or folders, whose changes you don't want in your repo to your .gitignore file. Once you have done that you have to commit that change into your repository to put it into effect. Then any changes to them will simply be ignored by git.

Comment: Thanks a lot.It worked. Changed the git repo folder as well.

Comment: You're welcome. If it helped you pls consider accepting the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want GIT to stop tracking them you need to look at [.gitignore](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore) which stops git tracking these files in the future. Once you've added them to .gitignore you'll need to remove them from your repository if they already exist there by using the `git rm` command.

Comment: Thanks for the response. The problem has been solved.

Answer (score 0):

Thisi thread is old, but I've been in this situation, so this may help others...

1. To get rid of all the changes since the last commit, the simplest is to stash them (in vscode: Git icon > 3 dots > Stash > Stash).
   You tried Drop Stash, but that will only drop existing stashes.
   Once stashed, you can forget about the changes if you don't need them anymore, or you can retrieve them if you change your mind.
2. If you can't find your commits in the **log**, then look up the **reflog**. Git makes its own reasonable assumptions on what you want to see or not see in the history, but sometimes you want the whole story.

Here are a couple of rules I found while using Git:

1. when Git asks you whether you are sure of something, then it's usually not a good idea. It usually means you are going to delete part of your history, which you don't want to do, except in some exotic situations.
2. if you haven't explicitly requested and confirmed that you want to delete something, then it's still there somewhere.